# How crawlable is Ember Cli?

Tags: ember-cli

I've been developing my own [personal website](http://deovandski.herokuapp.com/) for some time now, and I noticed that there are absolutely no search results except the Github repo and other related resources.

So, is pre-rendering with [ember-prerender](https://github.com/zipfworks/ember-prerender) or creating some other noJS solution the way to go for Ember.js? Or does Ember CLI handles crawling quite well, but the problem is either in my Project setup or Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The links posted here are no way in shape or form endorsements, but simply a possible solution to the Ember CLI SEO problem at hand.**

Post edited on 3/3/16

### [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)

The solution that I tried to use for my website. It allows up to 250 pages to be indexed for free which works perfectly for small websites. Pricing for large website seems fair as the startup tier gets 20k pages for $15 a month.

If you are deploying to Heroku using the [heroku-buildpack-ember-cli](https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli#prerenderio), then you can quickly set it up because of [Pull #41](https://github.com/tonycoco/heroku-buildpack-ember-cli/pull/41).

1. Add `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to your index.html
2. Create an account on [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) to get a token.
3. heroku config:set PRERENDER_HOST=service.prerender.io
4. heroku config:set PRERENDER_TOKEN=token

### [SEO.js](http://getseojs.com/)

I haven't used it, so I can only say that this one offers 100 snapshots for free...

### [BroomBone.com](http://www.brombone.com/#price)

Seems to be more business related. I consider checking out if your website is big enough...